# How to solve "Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly"? 2023 windows 11

Tags: windows, apache, xampp, window

How to solve "Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly"? 2023

How to solve "Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly"?

How to solve "Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly"?

How to solve "Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly"?

How to solve "Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly"?
How to solve "Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly"?

How to solve "Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly"?

How to solve "Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly"?

Answer (score 0):

You just have to install the latest :-
1.Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable packages for Visual Studio 2019, and 2022.
2. PHP and add the path in Environment Variables

That's it.
Now Run Apache.

Comment: Its unlikely that a missing PHP installation is resulting in unexpected shutdown

Comment: It simply did not have the dependencies (minimum requirements) installed in its computer.